# Why does it matter in which order I add attributes to a filter?

Tags: collection, sql, magento2.4

Compare this code

```
    $productIdQuery = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_group')
        ->addAttributeToFilter([
            ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'finset' => (int)$customerGroupId], 
            ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'eq' => ''],
            ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'null' => true],
        ]);
```

to this code

```
    $productIdQuery = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_group')
        ->addAttributeToFilter([
            ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'null' => true],
            ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'eq' => ''],
            ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'finset' => (int)$customerGroupId], 
        ]);
```

It gives different results. In the old code, rows with missing attribute value entries in the data base are missing.

Is this intended?

Answer (score 1):

The resulting queries differ:

```
SELECT `e`.*,
       IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value) AS `customer_group`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
         INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_customer_group_default`
                    ON (`at_customer_group_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
                       (`at_customer_group_default`.`attribute_id` = '161') AND
                       `at_customer_group_default`.`store_id` = 0
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_customer_group`
                   ON (`at_customer_group`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
                      (`at_customer_group`.`attribute_id` = '161') AND (`at_customer_group`.`store_id` = 1)
WHERE ((FIND_IN_SET(0, IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value))) OR
       (IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value) = '') OR
       (IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value) IS NULL))
```

vs.

```
SELECT `e`.*,
       IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value) AS `customer_group`
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_customer_group_default`
                   ON (`at_customer_group_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
                      (`at_customer_group_default`.`attribute_id` = '161') AND
                      `at_customer_group_default`.`store_id` = 0
         LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_customer_group`
                   ON (`at_customer_group`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
                      (`at_customer_group`.`attribute_id` = '161') AND (`at_customer_group`.`store_id` = 1)
WHERE ((IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value) IS NULL) OR
       (IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value) = '') OR
       (FIND_IN_SET(0, IF(at_customer_group.value_id > 0, at_customer_group.value, at_customer_group_default.value))))
```

The JOIN types differ.

This seems to happen here

```
vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php:1505

if (isset($condition['null'])) {
    $joinType = 'left';
}
```

So if the first condition is a "IS NULL" condition, Magento builds the join implicitly as left join.

A better solution might be to write

```
$productIdQuery = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_group')
    ->addAttributeToFilter([
        ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'finset' => (int)$customerGroupId], 
        ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'eq' => ''],
        ['attribute' => 'customer_group', 'null' => true],
    ], null, 'left');
```